# How can I get the correct JSON text in AFNetworking in swift

Tags: ios, json

I used AFNetworking to make a GET request. The result I got is not a JSON string but it should be a JSON string.

I want to get the following JSON text:

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "message": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "goods_id": "31",
      "goods_item": "DA55098",
      "goods_price": "0",
      "goods_shop_price": "198",
      "class_id": "45",
      "goods_thumbnail_image": "/public/upload/goods/20151122/thumb_fcd13f057fa51d2d72826f7e26625b7c.jpg",
      "goods_name": "Product name",
      "buy_num": 0,
      "faverite_num": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I got this:

```
{
    code = 200;
    data =     (
                {
            "buy_num" = 0;
            "class_id" = 45;
            "faverite_num" = 0;
            "goods_id" = 31;
            "goods_item" = DA55098;
            "goods_name" = "Product name";
            "goods_price" = 0;
            "goods_shop_price" = 198;
            "goods_thumbnail_image" = "/public/upload/goods/20151122/thumb_fcd13f057fa51d2d72826f7e26625b7c.jpg";
        }
    );
    message = "success";
}
```

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let api = "http://jjd.imlc.me/api/index/"

            manager.GET(
                api,
                parameters: nil,
                success: onSuccess,
                failure: onFailure
            )
        }


        func onSuccess(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void{
            let description = responseObject.description
            print(description)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the response serializer of your manager to an instance of AFJSONResponseSerializer like so (before you make your request)

```
manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing a JSON document converted to text with a JSON document, parsed and converted to a dictionary, and it's description displayed.

The description of a dictionary is not a JSON document. What you see is normal. Nothing to worry about.